# Separate database or new tables for new modules in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, schema, scalability

There are various modules in my application like -

1. Content Management
2. Expense Management and Payments
3. Scheduling Management

What is the best method to create the schema for the above scenario -

1. Have separate tables
2. Have separate DB for each

What are the advantages/disadvantages in terms of scalability, code maintainability and business point of view?

Answer (score 1):

Take your decision based on the following questions.

How much these different data sets are related.

What do you want to do with the data? Is it for some purpose like analytics or just to serve content over web through some applications?

Now there are quite a lot services provided by aws or gcp itself for content management and scheduling, Expense management you might have to build on your own with the database set up and everything.